# C segmentation fault after altering argv

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv

I want to change the values of `argv` in C, but I'm getting a segmentation fault. Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; argv[i]; i++)
    {
        char *val;

        printf("before: %d %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        argv[i] = "bar=foo";
        printf("after: %d %s\n", i, argv[i]);

        char *arg = argv[i];
        val = strchr(arg, '=');
        *val = '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm passing the argument `foo=bar` (and try to change it in line 11 to `bar=foo`). The output looks like this:

```
before: 1 foo=bar
after: 1 bar=foo
```

So, the modification actually takes place, but the line `*val = '\0';` causes a segmentation fault.

Can somebody tell me why this is and how I can prevent it?

Comment: if you are passing only 1 parameter then argv[i] is only valid if i takes on value 0. in your for loop the first iteration you are checking for argv[1] as a predicate to see if you should keep looping, but this will not work.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII `argv[0]` is always the name of the program, if you pass one arg, `argv[1]` is valid and `argv[2]` should be [`NULL`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020198/2666289).

Comment: @Holt `argv[0]` can be `NULL`.  C11 §5.1.2.2.1 2

Comment: @Holt: 1) `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. A pointer cannot be a macro. It can be a _null pointer_, however, which equals a _null pointer constant_. 2) Please point me at where the standard says `argv[2]` has to be a null pointer.

Comment: @Olaf The [link](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) in my previous comment: `argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.`.

Comment: @Holt "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer. — If the value of argc is greater than zero, ..." So with `argc == 0`, `argv[0]` is the null pointer.  IOWs C does not require "argv[0] is always the name of the program".  Further "**If the value of argc is greater than zero**, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name;"

Comment: @chux You are right, I realized my mistake a bit after posting my comment...

Comment: @Holt: I stand corrected. Overread the line in the standard. (btw: I asked for a pointer to the standard, i.e. the authoritative reference). FYI: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2 2nd item.

Comment: By the way, why are you using `strchr` like that instead of e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)?

Comment: As commented below your answer, I'm modifying a well established tool, i.e, the tool was already using `strchr`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You make `argv[i]` point to a *string literal*, which is an array of *read-only* characters. Then you attempt to modify this read-only array leading to *undefined behavior*.

There's a reason you should be using `const char *` for string literals.

---

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. The first and simplest, especially if you are going to use the same string for all arguments (not very likely except in a contrived examples such as the one you show) is to use an array, like `char argument[] = "bar=foo";`. Relying on the natural decay of arrays to pointers to their first arguments, you could use that in the assignment to `argv[i]` instead, and modify the array to your hearts content.

But like I said that won't really be very useful except for simple examples. That leaves us with another option, using e.g. `strdup` to dynamically allocate and copy the strings (alternatively if `strdup` is not available, it's not a standard function, you could manually use `malloc` and `strcpy`). Since you then have dynamically allocated the memory it can also be modified to your hearts content. The problem here is that you then need to keep track of the original pointers and use `free` to free them again.

So these are basically the two solutions you could use.One is unrealistic, and the other have dynamic memory allocations and all the problem that entails. There are really no good and especially no *simple* solutions to your problem.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not sure how to use `const char*` then to modify `argv[i]`?

Comment: @drZaius You can't, it's was mostly that when dealing with string literals you really need to think about their read-only aspects. I did however edit the answer to include a couple of possible solutions.

Comment: True, I was actually modifying a tool that's available to every Unix machine (but shall remain nameless). Right before you further explained, I tried using an array and it actually did the job! So no seg fault anymore and my modification is up and running.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing to a string literal here

```
val = strchr(arg, '=');
*val = '\0';
```

String literals live in the read only segment of the program, and trying to alter them invokes undefined behavior.

After this line

```
argv[i] = "bar=foo";
```

`argv[i]` points to a string literal `"bar=foo"` you then, create a new pointer `arg` that points to `argv[i]` and finally `val` a poitner to the `=` in `arg` which you then go and try to overwrite with a `nul`.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault happens because of the attempt to write to the read-only memory. In your example, you are attempting to modify a string literal `"bar=foo"` through `val` pointer. Your compiler placed this string literal in a segment in the executable file that in your execution environment was loaded to a memory region with read-only access.

The compiler could have placed this string literal in a different segment or the execution environment could have not had writing restriction to the memory region where the string literal was loaded. In that case, you would not have had a segmentation fault.

Since the C standard does not require string literals to be always placed in a read-only memory region during execution, in some cases they can be successfully modified while in others this operation is not allowed, and that is why the standard says:

> (C90, 6.1.4) "If the program attempts to modify a string literal of
> either form, the behavior is undefined"

This situation could have been avoided by specifying `-Wwrite-strings` option for GCC and Clang compilers when compiling the given sample. This option makes string literals const-qualified (they are not by default), thus triggering the warning when string literals are assigned to non-const pointer variables that could be used to modify memory behind string literals that could be located in a read-only region.

```
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   11 |         argv[i] = "bar=foo";
      |                 ^
```

By also specifying `-Werror` or `-Werror=discarded-qualifiers` and treating the warning as an error you would have catched the mistake before execution because the sample would not have been compiled.