# Can exec*'s argv contain a value of 0 in multiple places?

Tags: linux, x86, exec, posix, abi

I was reading that after `exec` creates a new process,

> **argv** is an array of argument strings, with `argv[argc] == 0`

What happens if one of the other values within the array `argv` happens to be 0? Will the number of arguments (`argc`) be incorrectly calculated when the child process runs?

I read this on page 34 of the ABI of AMD64 (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execve` system call (which is used by all `exec*` functions) has an argument of the form `char *const argv[]`. The kernel calculates `argc` by iterating over the supplied `argv` as [follows](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/299f89d53e61c0b17479cc7d6f3b5382d5e83f28/fs/exec.c#L462):

```
static int count(struct user_arg_ptr argv, int max)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (argv.ptr.native != NULL) {
        for (;;) {
            const char __user *p = get_user_arg_ptr(argv, i);

            if (!p)
                break;

            if (IS_ERR(p))
                return -EFAULT;

            if (i >= max)
                return -E2BIG;
            ++i;

            if (fatal_signal_pending(current))
                return -ERESTARTNOHAND;
            cond_resched();
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

The function `get_user_arg_ptr` essentially calculates an index into the `argv` array and returns the pointer stored at that index. The loop breaks under four conditions, two of them are pertinent to your question:

- On the first `NULL` seen in the argv array. If there are other pointers following the first `NULL` in `argv`, they are ignored. Having more than one `NULL` smells like a bug in the program that constructed `argv`.
- When the number of pointers is larger than or equal to `MAX_ARG_STRINGS`, which is [defined](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ead751507de86d90fa250431e9990a8b881f713c/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h#L16) as `0x7FFFFFFF`. In this case, the system call fails.

The value of `i` returned is assigned to `argc` when `get_user_arg_ptr` returns.

Another case where the terminating `NULL` in `argv` matters is when the application itself uses `argv` as follows:

```
for(char **p = argv; *p != NULL; ++p)
{
   // ...
}
```

It's part of the Linux ABI that `argv` terminates with `NULL`, so such code is legal and portable across all Linux implementations. By the way, this code is legal too on Windows. Therefore, `argc` is provided for convenience only.

In addition, both the C and C++ standards state in 5.1.2.2.1 and 3.6.1, respectively, that if `argc` is larger than zero, then all values in `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` shall be non-null pointers to null-terminated strings. Also `argv[argc]` must be null and that `argc` is non-negative. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020172/are-char-argv-arguments-in-main-null-terminated) answer.